# Remmina not receiving audio

Tags: networking, sound, remote-desktop, remmina

I have two PCs both running Ubuntu 19.10. I need to remote control one of them with the other one, so I enabled screen sharing (`Settings > Sharing > Screen sharing`) for the "server" and connected to it with Remmina from the "client". It works, except that the client doesn't receive audio, which I need.

How can I enable audio receiving? In Remmina I can't find any audio related setting.

Comment: did you solve your problem? I have the same issue under ubuntu 20.04 when I installed latest version from snap , old version works ok when I install it from PPA

Comment: @eshirvana no, I still can't receive audio.

Answer (score 1):

actually it was a bug in remmina that got fixed couple of days ago ,

you can get that bug fix by refreshing snap from edge channel :

```
sudo snap refresh remmina --channel=edge
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I installed Remmina snap version 4924 and there is an option on `Connection -> Advanced -> Audio output mode`, and I set it to `Remote`, now the audio is correctly outputting on the remote machine.