# What is the correct configuration for Remmina to receive/produce audio from the source?

Tags: networking, sound, soundcard, lan, remmina

In the same LAN exists some laptops with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04. All of them have enabled remote connection. For 2 of them is used Remmina to get access to the others through the same LAN.
So far this approach works as expected. Therefore:

```
Client ----> Source
```

**Note**: Remmina is already installed by default in Ubuntu.

The goal is that from the client to the source is opened a web browser at YouTube to play a video with audio and should happen any of the following scenarios:

- listen the audio **only** in the client
- listen the audio in the client and source

I've already read the following posts:

- [How to remote linux desktop with audio support](https://superuser.com/questions/720772/how-to-remote-linux-desktop-with-audio-support)
- [Remmina not receiving audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227585/remmina-not-receiving-audio)

And even watched this video

- [Remote Desktop from Ubuntu to Windows with Sound Redirection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CXKSP739tU)

But does not work as expected, the audio is **always only** produced/emitted in the source and not in the client.

Therefore

- `Advanced` -> `Audio` -> tried with each option

Does not work. What is missing?